# can'nt able to render page with Session Provider next js auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I've got a problem with Session Provider. I nextAuth lib to sign in with credentials, the problem is.
**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

```
    import { ChangeLanguageDocumentAttributes } from "../helpers";
    import {
      ReactElement,
      ReactNode,
      createContext,
      useEffect,
      useState,
    } from "react";
    import ToastNottfication, {
      ToastNottficationtype,
    } from "../components/atoms/app-notification/toast";
    import toast, { ToastBar, Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
    import AppNotification from "../components/atoms/app-notification";
    import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
    import type { NextPage } from "next";
    
    import "../i18n/index";
    import "../styles/globals.css";
    import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
    import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
    import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
    interface ToastContextInterface {
      toast: null | any | ToastNottficationtype[];
      setToast: React.Dispatch<
        React.SetStateAction<any | ToastNottficationtype[] | null>
      >;
      success: (title: string, message?: string) => void;
      error: (title: string, message?: string) => void;
    }
    
    export type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
      getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
    };
    
    type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
      Component: NextPageWithLayout;
    };
    export const ToastContext = createContext<ToastContextInterface | null>(null);
    async function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
      const [currentToast, setCurrentToast] = useState<
        null | any | ToastNottficationtype[]
      >(null);
      const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);
      const queryClient = new QueryClient();
    
      const showSuccessToast = (title: string) => {
        setCurrentToast([
          ...(currentToast || []),
          {
            massgesKey: title,
            type: "success",
          },
        ]);
      };
    
      const showErrorToast = (title: string) => {
        setCurrentToast([
          ...(currentToast || []),
          {
            massgesKey: title,
            type: "error",
          },
        ]);
      };
      const toastContext = {
        toast: currentToast,
        setToast: setCurrentToast,
        success: showSuccessToast,
        error: showErrorToast,
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        ChangeLanguageDocumentAttributes();
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <ToastContext.Provider value={toastContext}>
            {!!currentToast &&
              currentToast?.length! > 0 &&
              currentToast?.map(
                (Nottficationt: ToastNottficationtype, index: number) => {
                  return (
                    <ToastNottfication
                      key={index}
                      massgesKey={Nottficationt.massgesKey}
                      type={Nottficationt.type}
                    />
                  );
                }
              )}
            <Toaster position="top-right">
              {(t) => (
                <ToastBar toast={t}>
                  {({ icon, message }) => (
                    <AppNotification
                      message={message}
                      type={t.type}
                      onClose={() => toast.dismiss(t.id)}
                    />
                  )}
                </ToastBar>
              )}
            </Toaster>
            <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
              {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
            </SessionProvider>
          </ToastContext.Provider>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      );
    }
    
    export default MyApp;
```

[image: browser error]

need Next Auth Sign in With Credentials

Comment: This error occur because you are rendering the `Promise Object` instead to result